# which browser emulation software has the widest range of browsers / devices?

Tags: testing, browser, emulation

which browser testing software has the widest range of browsers / devices?

I'm looking for something that will allow connecting to remote devices for full device emulation as opposed to simply responsive design testing.

I'd also (if it exists) like one that allows testing on "in-app" browsers such as apps like Facebook, Instagram, Youtube, Gmail etc.

The Facebook in-app browser must surely be rising to the top of most widely used browser list yet I've seen no reliable way to test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain it is exactly what you are looking for, but the [Xamarin Test Cloud](https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud) will test an app against over 2000 Android devices.  You could set up your site as a simple web browser app to test it.